# Delete files with double quotes in their names

Tags: linux, ubuntu-16.04

I have some files with names like this:

```
name_"some thing".svg
```

I can't do any operation with them. Move, rename, delete, edit, etc. How can I rename or delete these files?

I already googled and searched here for the problem, but no solution presented worked for me. I always get the same error:

```
No such file or directory.
```

The complete path to them is:

```
/media/bruno/HDD Externo/temp/
```

It's an USB External HDD.

Comment: In such cases I use the midnight commander (mc): mark the file with the INS key and press F8 to remove the marked file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delete the files containing double quotes `""`, you can do this.

```
find . -type f -name '*"*"*.svg' -exec rm -f -- {} +
```

Edit: You need to first go to your file path and then execute above command.

```
cd /media/bruno/HDD Externo/temp/
```

Comment: Nothing happens, no message and the files are still there.

Comment: @FallAndLearn make that pattern a `-name '*"*"*.svg'` since the quotes are inside the filename.

Comment: pls accept my answer if it helped you

Answer (score 5):

Enclose file names in single quotes:

```
rm 'name_"some thing".svg'
```

You can also escape double quotes and space with a backslash:

```
rm name_\"some\ thing\".svg
```

As a precaution, it is always good to invoke `rm` with the `-i` option, to protect against accidentally losing a file.

In general, we can use single quotes to protect double quotes and vice-versa.

Comment: I did that as my first try, it gets me the "No such file..." message. The same happens with rm $'filename'

Comment: @BrunoCaxito: rm $'filename' won't expand the variable.  Please paste the command you are using.